# python opencv import libraries error

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run the facedetect.py sample code : [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/facedetect.py)

but I don't really understand what are these two line in the import section

```
from video import create_capture
from common import clock, draw_str
```

this error is displayed :

```
from video import create_capture
ImportError: No module named video
```

What are these libraries and how can I install them?

Comment: it's video.py and common.py, in the same samples/python2 folder

Answer (score 2):

i think you are using opencv samples..to run it you copy video.py and common.py files from the folder to C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\ or you need to have these files in the same folder so that python can detect it is available.

they have used functions from video module so you need to include them.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the repository [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/python2) , you'll find **video.py** and **common.py** . You need this to run the file. Perhaps you need their dependencies too (other files)